# link_to does undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

After using this code to get my link to show me 3 database entrys as link in table i get undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass error this error for companies without these fields.

```
<td><%= link_to  @company.office_adress_street + ", " + @company.office_adress_city + ", " + @company.office_adress_postcode, "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + @company.office_adress_street + ", " + @company.office_adress_city + ", " + @company.office_adress_postcode, :target => '_blank' %></td>
```

Comment: Is it intended, that some of these fields are not present for some companies?

Comment: @FlyingFoX yes, some companies can be not present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check that each of those calls to attributes of @company.XXX do not return nil, and better yet string concatenation should be structured like:

```
"#{link_to(@company.office_adress_street)}, #{@company.office_adress_city}, #{@company.office_adress_postcode}"
```

Comment: I am a rails beginner. Any tips how to do the check not to return nil and why your suggested structure is better ?

Comment: #{} will handles nils better (it won't throw an exception as it does with calling +() on a nil object). To check whether to return nil you could do an inline condition such as #{@company.office_address_city.nil ? "" : @company.office_address_city.nil} which will either return "" or the value of the attribute.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you add a method to your model (or to a decorator)

```
def address
  [office_address_street, office_address_city, office_address_postcode].compact.join(', ')
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<td><%= link_to  @company.address, "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + @company.address, :target => '_blank' %></td>
```

If you do decide to use a decorator, you could also create a method `link_to_address` that returns the link, then simplify the view to:

```
<td><%= @company.link_to_address %></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `@company` has a `office_adress_street` attribute (etc...) and that it isn't `nil` (It is expecting `@company.office_adress_street` to be a string).

Perhaps there is a typo? `adress` or `address`?

If it is intended that `@company` sometimes has no `office_adress_street` attribute, use the [link_to_if](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if) helper:

`<td><%= link_to_if @company.office_adress_street, @company.office_adress_street + ", " + @company.office_adress_city + ", " + @company.office_adress_postcode, "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + @company.office_adress_street + ", " + @company.office_adress_city + ", " + @company.office_adress_postcode, :target => '_blank' %></td>`

Comment: I think this did not solve my problem, because any of attributes above can have no value put in.

Comment: Yes, sorry. In this case, add a method to your model like John suggests which brings them all together in to one attribute.